# Where can I find 3d models of equipment for supermarket?

Tags: models

Where can I find 3d models of equipment  for supermarket? I will use them in XNA.

UPD. I need equipment like this http://www.the3dstudio.com/product_details.aspx?id_product=419747 without products.

Comment: Voted to close as too localized. I can see 'where can I find 3D models of people' as a valid question, but supermarket equipment seems very niche-like.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [turbosquid.com](http://www.turbosquid.com/Search/Index.cfm?keyword=supermarket&x=0&y=0).

Answer (score 2):

first of all, i don't know any particular website for this, but i can help you out.

What file types does you current 3d environment support?
search [Google sketch-up library online](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/search?q=supermarket&styp=m&btnG=Vyhledat&reps=2&start=0), it has lots of 3d models.

if you found what you need, then check if you 3d apps file type is supported in Google sketch-up.

if yes download Google sketch-up, download the model from Google site and do the conversion manually.

the reason i suggest this is that Google sketch-up has lots of models you can download free, depending on the owners terms.

if you have any problem converting, let me know
i have done lots of conversion like these when doing 3d games